# Failed test #5 of 25. Cannot check answer. Perhaps output format is wrong

Tags: python

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input()) 
d = 1
while d%a!=0 or d%b!=0:
    d+=1
    if d%a==0 and d%b==0:
        print(int(d))
        break
```

В компиляторе код работает как надо, но stepik.ru ругается , что `Failed test #5 of 25. Cannot check answer. Perhaps output format is wrong.`

Программа должна считывать размеры команд (два положительных целых числа aa и bb, каждое число вводится на отдельной строке) и выводить наименьшее число dd, которое делится на оба этих числа без остатка.

```
Sample Input 1:

1
2
Sample Output 1:

2
Sample Input 2:

7
5
Sample Output 2:

35
Sample Input 3:

15
15
Sample Output 3:

15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наименьшее общее кратное `lcm` можно найти быстрее, без перебора, зная наибольший общий делитель `gcd`. Он есть в стандартной библиотеке `math`:

```
import math

a = int(input())
b = int(input())

lcm = (a * b) // math.gcd(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2):

проковырявшись над этим почти весь день, я пришёл к такому решению))

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
e = [a, b]
i = min(e)
while True:
    if i%a==0 and i%b==0:
        break
    i += 1
print(i)
```